# Unusual error with string in canvas in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas

I tried to make a falling snow in canvas. The code works ok in Chrome but in FF18 nothing is displayed.

http://dharman.eu/flakes/

When I checked it in console Firebug throws this error:
*An invalid or illegal string was specified*
`var s = flakes[flake].chara;`
`ctx.fillText(s,flakes[flake].x, flakes[flake].y);`

Any Ideas what is wrong with my code?

Also The width of canvas element seems to be too big even though it is specified to be 100%. Why?

```
var screenH = window.innerHeight;
var screenW = window.innerWidth;
canvas.width = screenW;
canvas.height = screenH;
```

Comment: The width and height issue is caused by unwanted margin of `body`.

Comment: Have you tried to use simple stars `*` instead of Unicode snowflakes?

Comment: Sorry but asterisk makes no difference, still the same error appears

Comment: There is a conflict with the variable `flakes` in `drawFlakes`.

Comment: Oh wait, it says `flakes[flake].y` is `undefined`.

Comment: Where did you get that?

Comment: Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/jMxYP/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `init();` to the bottom of your code and then it will work:

```
//...

$('#canvas').dblclick(function () {
    RunPrefixMethod(canvas, "RequestFullScreen");
});

//width/height 100%
var screenH = window.innerHeight;
var screenW = window.innerWidth;
canvas.width = screenW;
canvas.height = screenH;

init();  //<--here
```

Because `screenH` is not defined. (Strange...)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/jNf47/

---

## Bonus: Debugging

First, I know one of the variables in `ctx.fillText` is not defined, so I have to find out which one is it:

```
console.log(s,flakes[flake].x, flakes[flake].y);
//[some number], [some number], undefined)
```

So the problem is in `flakes[flake].y`. It seems like `flakes[flake].y` is referring to `screenH`, so that means `screenH` is the problem. Usually variables have to be defined before you call `init()`, so I just moved it to the bottom and it works.

Comment: @Dharman - Here's a [useful website](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) about debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the order of your code.

You call init() which starts your animation running before you set these variables

```
var screenH = window.innerHeight;
var screenW = window.innerWidth;
```

Then in the drawFlakes loop you attempt to assign the flakes y value to screenH (which is undefined)

```
else
{   
  flakes[flake].y=screenH;
  flakes[flake].die-=33;
}
```

then finally when it comes to render the flake

```
ctx.fillText(s,flakes[flake].x, flakes[flake].y);
```

y is undefined and causes you the error.